# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$ using "GAP language"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, gap

How can I know the nontrivial subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$ (with multiplication without zero) using **GAP language**

Comment: The best place to ask a question about GAP is the GAP Forum (http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html). I don't know if you have already tried that, but they are usually very helpful.

Comment: @ManolitoPérez: thanks for pointing out to the GAP Forum :)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: My pleasure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create the field:

```
gap> F:=GF(13);
GF(13)
```

Next, calculate its unit group:

```
gap> U:=Units(F);
<group of size 12 with 1 generators>
```

One could be interested in some of its properties:

```
gap> Size(U);
12
gap> IsCyclic(U);
true
```

Now, for such a small example one could just use `AllSubgroups`:

```
gap> s:=AllSubgroups(U);
[ <trivial group>, <group of size 2 with 1 generators>, 
  <group of size 3 with 1 generators>, <group of size 4 with 1 generators>, 
  <group of size 6 with 2 generators>, <group of size 12 with 1 generators> ]
```

Then filter only non-trivial subgroups:

```
gap> s1 := Filtered(s, g -> not Size(g) in [1,Size(U)]);
[ <group of size 2 with 1 generators>, <group of size 3 with 1 generators>, 
  <group of size 4 with 1 generators>, <group of size 6 with 2 generators> ]
```

For example, the second group from this list consists of these elements:

```
gap> AsList(s2[3]);
[ Z(13)^0, Z(13)^8, Z(13)^4 ]
```

Note that the subgroups are not necessarily given by generating sets of minimal possible order.

Comment: When I'm trying the fourth step, I have the massege: 'AllSubgroups' must have a value

Comment: `AllSubgroups` is documented [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X80399CD4870FFC4B) - perhaps you're using outdated version of GAP? Try `ConjugacyClassesSubgroups` and then use `Representative` to find a representative of each class (which will be a singleton since the group is abelian)

Comment: P.S. I have GAP 4.5.7 around (December 2012) and even there `AllSubgroups` is available - it was introduced in one of GAP 4.5 releases, don't remember which. Definitely it was not available in GAP 4.4.12 in 2008. So I very much recommend to update to the latest GAP 4.7.8 (June 2015) - not because you will have a toy function `AllSubgroups` which will work with small examples, but because it contains lots of new functionality and bugfixes. Regarding all subgroups, see also [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7).

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need GAP for this task.

Since $13$ is prime, $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$ is a cyclic group of order $12$. Thus all subgroups are cyclic and the lattice of subgroups corresponds to the lattice of divisors of $12$.

To be explicit, $2$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$. Thus all subgroups are generated by $2^d$ where $d$ is a divisor of $12$.

Comment: I solved this without using GAP already, but I want to check my answers, same like Wolfram Alpha in calcules

Comment: (+1) - indeed! @Nehorai, if you know that the group is cyclic, you can of course investigate `CyclicGroup(12)` without constructing a field. Or, if you know further part of the theory, you may call `DivisorsInt(12)` to get the list of divisors. So in your check you may combine the knowledge you have from theory with the part of the GAP functionality that you hopefully know already, instead of trying to figure out how to reproduce the whole example from scratch.